# Extra evaluation time when using GPU compared to CPU

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

Since I am still very new to Tensorflow, I don't know what caused this problem. I am currently using Tensorflow to do text classification. I needed the timing to evaluate 1 data since I need precision. When I time the evaluation time in CPU, the time required is constant while there seems to be additional time when using GPU.

Here is the statistics:

- Using GPU:

  ```
     1 data -->  300 ms.
    10 data -->  300 ms. 30 ms each.
   100 data -->  400 ms.  4 ms each.
  1000 data --> 4000 ms.  4 ms each.
  ```
- Using CPU :

  ```
     1 data -->    10 ms.
    10 data -->   100 ms. 10 ms each.
   100 data -->  1000 ms. 10 ms each.
  1000 data --> 10000 ms. 10 ms each.
  ```

Comment: You've shown no code making it impossible to help.

Comment: It looks like using GPU is faster in the long run, but it requires some setup time regardless of data size. That seems reasonable to me.